# What is the best way to structure a group of variables that have a group of variables that have a group of variables and so on?

Tags: java, data-structures, object-oriented-analysis

I'm creating a Java program which calculates rates. The rate has a season which has its peaks and those peaks have their own hours and prices. I was thinking of doing nested classes, but there's got to be a better way that I'm just not thinking about it right?

Variables that I need to store:

```
Rate
    Summer
        peak
            hours
            price
        midpeak
            hours
            price
        off-peak
            hours
            price
    Non-summer
        peak
            hours
            price
        midpeak
            hours
            price
        off-peak
            hours
            price
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Alder ! Nice question but not for this site. I think the proper site for this question is https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Create the objects and model them. Why do you think nested classes are the answer?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I thought nested classes would be an organized way of storing the data. I'd be able to access a variable by doing something like Rate summer = new Rate();...summer.peak.rate = 1.12; summer.peak.hours[] = {...}; ... and if i wanted to set the summer's mid peak rate: summer.midPeak.rate = 1.00; though id probably have to use getters and setters but i think u get the idea.My other idea was using a multi-dimension array, but accessing variable wouldnt be descriptive at all. Where rate[0][1] refers to summer's peak's rate. It can get confusing.

Comment: @AlderMoreno that has nothing to do with nested classes. That has to do with composition.

Comment: @Christos sorry... im a noob to SO. So what is the difference between this site and the softwareengineering extension, in regards to appropriate questions?

Comment: @AlderMoreno You don't have to say sorry ! I think here you can find an answer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254570/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-software-engineering/254571#254571. On the other hand, posting here is by no means wrong. Just IMHO I thing that softwarengineering would be more suitable. Just my 2 cents. Thanks

Comment: @BoristheSprider gosh, you're right. That's what I need to look into then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach:

```
class BaseRate {
    int hours;
    int price;

    public BaseRate(int hours, int price) {
        this.hours = hours;
        this.price = price;
    }
}

class SeasonalRate {
    BaseRate peakRate;
    BaseRate midPeakRate;
    BaseRate offPeakRate;

    public SeasonalRate(BaseRate peakRate, BaseRate midPeakRate, BaseRate offPeakRate) {
        this.peakRate = peakRate;
        this.midPeakRate = midPeakRate;
        this.offPeakRate = offPeakRate;
    }
}

class AnnualRates {
    SeasonalRate summerRate;
    SeasonalRate winterRate;

    public AnnualRates(SeasonalRate summerRate, SeasonalRate winterRate) {
        this.summerRate = summerRate;
        this.winterRate = winterRate;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BaseRate peakWinterRateFor2019 = new BaseRate(1, 3);
        BaseRate midPeakWinterRateFor2019 = new BaseRate(1, 3);
        BaseRate offPeakWinterRateFor2019 = new BaseRate(1, 3);
        BaseRate peakSummerRateFor2019 = new BaseRate(1, 3);
        BaseRate midPeakSummerRateFor2019 = new BaseRate(1, 3);
        BaseRate offPeakSummerRateFor2019 = new BaseRate(1, 3);

        SeasonalRate winterRateFor2019 = new SeasonalRate(peakWinterRateFor2019, midPeakWinterRateFor2019, offPeakWinterRateFor2019);
        SeasonalRate summerRateFor2019 = new SeasonalRate(peakSummerRateFor2019, midPeakSummerRateFor2019, midPeakWinterRateFor2019);

        AnnualRates ratesFor2019 = new AnnualRates(summerRateFor2019, winterRateFor2019);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how I would set the rate for the peak period in the summer season? I'm not too familiar with enums so it would help me better understand this. Thank you Surya!

Comment: removed enums and added code to better suit your use case

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for thank you so much

Comment: you're welcome. can you accept my answer in that case.